# Trouble running UPNP on Docker

Tags: java, docker, containers, upnp, android-cling

I trying to run an UPnP service on my docker container using the Cling UPNP library (http://4thline.org/projects/cling/). There is a simple program that creates a device (in software) that hosts some service. This is written in Java and when I try to run the program I get the following exception **(Note: This runs perfectly fine directly on my Ubuntu machine)**:

```
Jun 5, 2015 1:47:24 AM org.teleal.cling.UpnpServiceImpl <init>
INFO: >>> Starting UPnP service...
Jun 5, 2015 1:47:24 AM org.teleal.cling.UpnpServiceImpl <init>
INFO: Using configuration: org.teleal.cling.DefaultUpnpServiceConfiguration
Jun 5, 2015 1:47:24 AM org.teleal.cling.transport.RouterImpl <init>
INFO: Creating Router: org.teleal.cling.transport.RouterImpl
Exception occured: org.teleal.cling.transport.spi.InitializationException: Could not discover any bindable network interfaces and/or addresses
org.teleal.cling.transport.spi.InitializationException: **Could not discover any bindable network interfaces and/or addresses
    at org.teleal.cling.transport.impl.NetworkAddressFactoryImpl.<init>(NetworkAddressFactoryImpl.java:99)**
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that finds this and needs the answer.

Your container is obscuring your external network. **In other words, by default  containers are isolated and cannot see the outer network** which is of course required in order to open the ports in your IGD.

You can run your container as a "host" to make it non isolated, **simply add `--network host` to your container creation command**.

Example (taken from https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/#procedure):

```
docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx
```

I have tested this using **docker-compose.yml** which looks a bit different:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  upnp:
    container_name: upnp
    restart: on-failure:10
    network_mode: host  # works while the container runs
    build:
      context: .
      network: host  # works during the build if needed
```

**version 3.4 is very important and the `network: host` will not work otherwise!**

My `upnp` container `Dockerfile` looks like so:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update
RUN apk add bash
RUN apk add miniupnpc

RUN mkdir /scripts
WORKDIR /scripts
COPY update_upnp .
RUN chmod a+x ./update_upnp

# cron to update each UPnP entries every 10 minutes
RUN echo -e "*/10\t*\t*\t*\t*\tbash /scripts/update_upnp 8080 TCP" >> /etc/crontabs/root

CMD ["crond", "-f"]

# on start, open needed ports
ENTRYPOINT bash update_upnp 80 TCP && bash update_upnp 8080 TCP
```

`update_upnp` script is simply using `upnpc` (installed as miniupnpc in the Dockerfile above) to open the ports.

Hopefully this will help somebody.

**Edit: Here is how `update_upnp` script may look like:**

```
#!/bin/bash

port=$1
protocol=$2
echo "Updating UPnP entry with port [$port] and protocol [$protocol]"

gateway=$(ip route | head -1 | awk '{print $3}')
echo "Detected gateway is [$gateway]"

# port - e.g. 80
# protocol - TCP or UDP
upnpc -e 'your-app-name' -r $port $protocol

echo "Done updating UPnP entry with port [$port] and protocol [$protocol]"
```

Comment: Is there no way to run a UPNP service without host mode?